# only show page if session isset and variable ==

Tags: php, session

i'm trying to add roles for certain pages on a small internal site i am running.

i assign the following sessions when user logs into the site login form;

```
// Register $username, $role Sessions and redirect
$_SESSION['username']= $username; 
$_SESSION['accessLevel'] = $role;
$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = true;
```

i then have the following on my logout.php page;

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: ../login.php");
?>
```

i want to restrict page based on the users $_SESSION['accessLevel']

for instance only show page if $_SESSION['accessLevel'] == 'admin' else redirect to login page (or error page)

here is what i have on an admin page;

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['accessLevel'] == 'admin'){ 
?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>ADMIN AREA!! </p>
 <p>username: <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></p>
 <p>Access: <?php echo $_SESSION['accessLevel'];?></p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
else {
    header("location:../login.php");
}
?>
```

now the page redirects to login.php when i login using admin credentials if i remove the check i print_r the sessions are correct;

$_SESSION['accessLevel'] = admin

$_SESSION['username'] = testuser

where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the `username` *to* exist, right now you are checking to see if it is *not* `isset()`. Update your conditional to:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['accessLevel'] == 'admin') { 
    // HTML here
} else {
    header("location:../login.php");
}
```

Also, a side note: if you ever have an edge case were you set a `username` value but *not* a `accessLevel` value, you will get a fatal error with this conditional. You should be making sure that the `accessLevel` is set to be safe:

```
isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['accessLevel']) && $_SESSION['accessLevel'] == 'admin'
```

Comment: "you will get a fatal error with this conditional": maybe, maybe not, depending on how your server is setup, but checking both are set is the best way to go.

Comment: great stuff, now it works. i'm unlikely to have 1 value and not the other so for now i will work with this. Thank you